# How can I detect CTRL+SHIFT+ANY_KEY using a KeyAdapter?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent, key-events

Here's my code:

```
        tabbedPane.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

                CheckShortcut controlShortcut = (key) -> {
                    return (evt.getKeyCode() == key) && ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0);
                };

                CheckShortcut controlShiftShortcut = (key) -> {
                    return (evt.getKeyCode() == key) && ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK & KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0);
                }; // Does not work <<<<<

                if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_N)) {
                    createNewFile();
                } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_O)) {
                    openFile();
                } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
                    save();
                } else if (controlShiftShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
                    saveAs();
                } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_Q)) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_W)) {
                    MainFrame.toggleFrame(qrWebcamFrame);
                } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_C)) {
                    MainFrame.toggleFrame(comandaCreationFrame);
                } else if (controlShortcut.f(KeyEvent.VK_P)) {
                    if (accessPasswordFrame("Senha de administrador",
                            "Login: ", "Senha de administrador inválida.",
                            ADMIN_TYPE)) {
                        MainFrame.toggleFrame(passwordFrame);
                    }
                }

            }   
        });
```

The `controlShortcut` works perfectly. Nevertheless, when I add `KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK` to the test, it does not work. Also, when I do this:

```
        CheckShortcut controlShiftShortcut = (key) -> {
            return (evt.getKeyCode() == key) && ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0) && ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0);
        };
```

It does not work as well. I don't understand why, since I'm just adding the same test.

Comment: You should be using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not how bitwise operators work. `KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK & KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK` always gives 0 because you are AND-ing different masks.

What you want to do is create a mask for both using OR:

```
int down = KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK;
if ((e.getModifiersEx() & down) == down && (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D))
    System.out.println(true);
```

This will print

> true

only when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is pressed.

If you write

```
(e.getModifiersEx() & down) != 0
```

it will check if *any* (or both) of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> are pressed.

Note that you should use `getModifiersEx` along with `X_DOWN_MASK` and not `getModifiers` along with `X_MASK`.

Comment: I was including this code as an "else if" clause, and it wasn't working because of that. I've discovered it only now. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @EricsonWillians Well, no one knoes what `CheckShortcut` is, so all we could do is show you how it's done and not find the and fix the error in your code. In the future, provide a [mcve]. You're welcome.

Comment: It's quite simple, actually. Just an interface: `interface CheckShortcut { Boolean f(int key); }`. I had to print the result of the test to discover that it was returning true. For some reason, it does not work as an "else if" clause of the simple `evt.getModifiers()` test.

Comment: @EricsonWillians It's simple now that you write it, but otherwise we can't know if it's simple or what it is. That line should have been in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong bitwise-operator on the masks.
See the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getModifiersEx())

The correct way should be:

```
int mask = CTRL_DOWN_MASK | SHIFT_DOWN_MASK;
if(evt.getModifiersEx() & mask == mask) {doStuff();}
```

See also the following methods:

```
evt.isControlDown();
evt.isAltDown();
evt.isShiftDown();
```

Comment: Something is wrong, none of them work, even with the alternative option: `return (evt.getKeyCode() == key) && evt.isControlDown() && evt.isShiftDown();`. 3 keys at the same time are not being recognized.

Comment: @EricsonWillians Something is wrong  - this answer. it checks for either control or shift.

Comment: @user1803551 please dont comment if you dont know what you are talking about. From the fact that even the && of methods didnt work, it means his logic is wrong

Comment: You've just edited your answer to copy mine while your previous one was wrong, and you tell me that I don't know what I'm talking about?

Comment: My answer as it was, was fine. His code didnt work because of some other reason, seeing as it didnt work with the "evt." Methods..

Comment: 1) Revenge downvotes won't get you anywhere. 2) Prove that your answer was fine. Show code that uses `evt.getModifiers() & (CTRL_MASK | SHIFT_MASK) != 0` to check for both shift and control as required. I offer you 100 reputation points via bounty if you can. If you can't, retract your offensive comment and admit your mistake. 3) Copying others' answers is not allowed on this site. 4) You have a compilation mistake in your updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create two boolean values for shift and control.

```
public class DummyClass implements KeyListener{
    boolean shift = false, control = false;

    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)
        {
            shift = true;
        }        
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
        {
            control = true;
        }
        if(shift && control)
        { 
            //Do something 
        }
        else if(shift)
        { 
            //Do something
        }
        else if(control)
        { 
            //Do something 
        }
    }
    public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT)
        {
            shift = false;
        }        
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
        {
            control = false;
        }
    }
}
```